# getting a value from an entry in a different class

Tags: python, tkinter

So i am trying to get the value from an entry in a different class but i can't get it to work, i tried to make to code as short as possible so hopefully you guys can help me

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import threading

class lingo(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        m = tk.Frame(self)
        m.grid(row=0, column=0,sticky="nsew")

        e1 = tk.Entry(m)
        e1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        def enter():
            entry1 = e1.get()
            t1 = threading.Thread(target=check)
            t1.start()

        b1 = tk.Button(m, bg="blue", text="enter", command=enter)
        b1.grid(row=0, column=1)

class check():
    def __init__(self):
            lingo1 = lingo()
            entry2 = lingo1.enter()
            entry3 = entry2.entry1()
            print(entry3)

t0 = threading.Thread(target=lingo)
t0.start()  
app = lingo()
app.wm_geometry("1810x1080")
app.resizable(False, False)
app.title("19 LetterWoordenLingo")
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Which value are you trying to get? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you should organize your code little bit.Here is a working example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import threading


class Lingo(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

      self.m = tk.Frame(self)
      self.m.grid(row=0, column=0,sticky="nsew")

      self.e1 = tk.Entry(self.m)
      self.e1.grid(row=0, column=0)

      b1 = tk.Button(self.m, bg="blue", text="enter", command= lambda :self.enter())
      b1.grid(row=0, column=1)

    def enter(self):
      object_check = Check(parent=self)
      t1 = threading.Thread(target=object_check.get_entry)
      t1.start()

class Check():
    def __init__(self, parent):
      self.parent = parent

    def get_entry(self):
      entry_text = self.parent.e1.get()
      print(entry_text)

if __name__ == '__main__':

  t0 = threading.Thread(target=Lingo)
  t0.start()
  app = Lingo()
  app.wm_geometry("1810x1080")
  app.resizable(False, False)
  app.title("19 LetterWoordenLingo")
  app.mainloop()
```

So you need to initiliaze your widgets. Then by pressing button, you can create an object of the class Check, which is then used for accesing the function defined in that class via new thread.

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Just handover the variable in the `__init__` method:

```
    (...)
    def enter():
        entry1 = e1.get()
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=check(entry1))
        t1.start()
    (...)    

class check():
    def __init__(self, entry1):
            (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call the lingo class in the init of check class and then create the object.

```
class check(lingo):
    def __init__(self):
        lingo.__init__(self)
        lingo1 = ClassA() 
        entry2 = lingo1.enter()
        entry3 = entry2.entry1()
        print(entry3)
```

I hope this helps.